# How can I keep my progress on Fortnite while signed into my Xbox with a different email address?

Tags: xbox-network, fortnite-battle-royale

My son (11) created himself as an adult, on Microsoft, and me (parent) as a child. So I cant set Xbox limits to limit Fortnite, because I have been created as a child.

How an I change his details on Microsoft to child, and mine to an adult, and still keep his progress?

If I cant do this, I have tried to sign in Xbox as myself, and set limits for myself, so this can limit screen time on Xbox for them. However, he cant then link his Xbox live progress while signed in as me. Can anyone help solving this difficult problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can login to Xbox as your child's account and then go to the Settings, then Account, And then choose **Family Settings**. After that you can change your account to adult settings and then change his settings to child settings.
This will enable you to limit the screen time and do anything else you want to do.
Hope this helps!